# Frappe Gantt chart date not aligning with correct date

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart, frappe

I'm using the [frappe gantt chart package](https://github.com/frappe/gantt) & setting the start date as "2022-04-18" but for some reason the bar is showing as one day before, is there a way for me to set an offset to correct this?

**Setting Items:**

```
return {
     start: '2022-04-18',
     end: '2022-05-20',
     name: project,
     id: "Task " + i,
     progress: 100,
};
```

**Setting Chart:**

```
var gantt2 = new Gantt("#gantt-1", tasks, {
    date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

I find out a fork.

[GitHub Fork](https://github.com/mmaarriioo/gantt)

and this work right.